# Exception is thrown while executing the INSERT statement

Tags: jsp

I'm getting following exception:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Column 'userid' cannot be null

```
<%@page import="java.io.InputStream"%>
<%@page import="conPackage.MyConnection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileInputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Enumeration"%>
<%@page import="com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest"%>
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        upload file page...!!!
        <%
            String rtempfile = File.createTempFile("temp","1").getParent();            
            MultipartRequest multi = new MultipartRequest(request,rtempfile, 15*1024*1024);     // maximum size 15 MB

            Enumeration files = multi.getFileNames();

String a=request.getParameter("uname");
String f=request.getParameter("email");
String b=request.getParameter("date");
String c=request.getParameter("gender");



            String st="insert into documents(userid,filename, type,date,type1,content, gender) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement psmt=MyConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(st);


            String name="";
            String fileExtesion="";
            File ff =null;
            FileInputStream fin =null;

            while (files.hasMoreElements())
            {
                    name=(String)files.nextElement();                                        
                    ff = multi.getFile(name);
                    fileExtesion = ff.getName().substring(ff.getName().lastIndexOf("."));

                    boolean fileAllowed = fileExtesion.equalsIgnoreCase(".txt")||
                                          fileExtesion.equalsIgnoreCase(".pdf")||
                                          fileExtesion.equalsIgnoreCase(".doc")||
                                          fileExtesion.equalsIgnoreCase(".docx")||
                                          fileExtesion.equalsIgnoreCase(".xls")||
                                          fileExtesion.equalsIgnoreCase(".xlsx");

                    if((ff!=null)&&fileAllowed)
                    {

                            try
                            {
                                    fin=new FileInputStream(ff);
                                     psmt.setString(1, a);
                                    psmt.setString(2, ff.getName());
                                    psmt.setString(3, fileExtesion);
                                     psmt.setString(4, b);
                                      psmt.setString(5, f);
                                    psmt.setBinaryStream(6,(InputStream)fin, (int)(ff.length()));
                                    psmt.setString(7, c);        // pass the user name or id 
                                    boolean sss = psmt.execute();

                                    out.print("uploaded successfully..");
                                    out.print("<br/> Go to <a href='downloadfile.jsp'>Download</a> page");
                            }

                            catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                    out.print("Failed due to " + e);
                            }

                            finally
                            {
                            // next statement is must otherwise file will not be deleted from the temp as fin using f.
                             // its necessary to put outside otherwise at the time of exception file will not be closed.
                                    fin.close();
                                    ff.delete();
                            }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                           out.print("Please select the correct file...");
                    }// end of if and else
            }// end of while

            MyConnection.CloseConnection();            
        %>
        <a href="sub.jsp">Home Page</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**my html code is:**

```
<%-- 
    Document   : sub
    Created on : Feb 20, 2015, 12:33:09 PM
    Author     : hcljava5
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>request</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/calendarview.css">

    <script src="js/calendarview.js"></script>

       <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="header"></div>
<div class="menu">

        <li><a href="sub.jsp">HOME</a></li>
</div>
       <div class="content">
           <center>
<b style="text-transform:uppercase; font-size:18px; color:#A31919;">Upload your Information</b></center><br>


<fieldset class="login">
<legend></legend>
        <form action="uploadfile.jsp" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <center><table>
                <tr>
                    <th>User ID</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="uname" required class="textbox"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email" required class="textbox"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                                        <td> <input type="date" name ="date" required class="textbox"></td>
                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Select Type</b> </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="gender" required class="textbox">
                        <option value="Publications">Publications</option>
                        <option value="Workshops">Workshops</option>
                                                <option value="conferences">conferences</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>   
                <tr>
                    <th>Upload File</th>
                    <td><input type="file" name="filename" id="filename" accept=".txt, application/pdf, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/msword" ></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="myButton" style="position:relative; left:130px;"></td>
                <td><input type = "reset" class="myButton" style="position:relative; left:150px;"></td>
                </tr>
                        </table> </center>
        </form>



       </div>
       <div class="footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My database table is created in my sql

Comment: What is your question? If you want people to look at your code and find bugs for you, at least indent it correctly, and use meaningful variables names: no a, b, c, d, etc.

Comment: Can you move your java code from JSP to Servlet. Never use Scriptlets.